# Schedule the shell script in different servers using same DAG file

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am completely new to Apache Airflow. I have a situation. The code I have used is

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook

default_args = {
                 'owner': 'john',
                 'depends_on_past': False,
                 'email': [''],
                 'email_on_failure': False,
                 'email_on_retry': False,
                 'retries': 0,
                 'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
               }
  
 dag = DAG(
            'tutorial',
            default_args = default_args,
            description='A simple tutorial DAG',
            schedule_interval=None)

bash_tutorial = """
  echo "Execute shell file: /A/B/server/tutorial.ksh"
  echo "{{macros.ds_format(ds, "%Y-%m-%d", "%m-%d-%Y"}}"
  source /home/johnbs/.profile
  /A/B/server/tutorial.ksh
 """

t1 = SSHOperator(
                ssh_conn_id='dev'
                task_id='tutorial.ksh'
                command=bash_tutorial,
                dag=dag
        )
```

Using airflow, I want to trigger a ksh script in different servers like dev and test servers i.e.

tutorial.ksh is present in dev server(conn_id is 'dev') of the path (/A/B/C/tutorial.ksh) and in test server(conn_id is 'test') of the path (/A/B/D/tutorial.ksh)...Here you can see C folder from dev and D folder from test...Which area should I update the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of `SSHOperator` execute a command on a single server.
You will need to define each connection separately as explained in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/connections/ssh.html#ssh-connection) and then you can do:

```
server_connection_ids = ['dev', 'test']
start_op = DummyOperator(task_id="start_task", dag=dag)
for conn in server_connection_ids:
    bash_tutorial = f"""
      echo "Execute shell file: /A/B/server/tutorial.ksh"
      echo "{{macros.ds_format(ds, "%Y-%m-%d", "%m-%d-%Y"}}"
      source /home/johnbs/.profile
      /A/B/{conn}/tutorial.ksh
     """
    ssh_op = SSHOperator(
        ssh_conn_id=f'{conn}',
        task_id=f'ssh_{conn}_task',
        command=bash_tutorial,
        dag=dag
    )
```

This will create a task per server.

Comment: bash_tutorial = """
  echo "Execute shell file: /A/B/server/tutorial.ksh"
  echo "{{macros.ds_format(ds, "%Y-%m-%d", "%m-%d-%Y"}}"
  source /home/johnbs/.profile
  /A/B/server/tutorial.ksh
 """      What do I need to mention in the path about the server? i.e./ A/B/?/tutorial.ksh?

Comment: Can someone help me understand the above solution please

Comment: I have updated the question by changing the path like ksh file present in particular folder in dev and test server..In dev, ksh file present in /A/B/C/tutorial.ksh... In test, its /A/B/D/tutorial.ksh

Comment: Your question seems to evolve and your current issue isnt related to Airflow. Its a matter of knowing to use python objects. You can change the list into dict storing all unique info related to each server. If you dont know how to do that you can open a new question with Python tag.